# tracking vehicle adminitration process

Tags: solution

Has anyone seen any good article(s) on vehicle tracking or maintenance list or list with workflow or a solid sharepoint solution. The needs are tracking registration, yearly license plate change, oil change, maintenance. etc.

I am thinking of a look up list for "ActionType" and it will list registration, license plate, oil change, maintenance, etc.

Then create another lookup list with vehicle information.

A 3rd list consuming data from above lookup lists with expiration date or days to valid (like oil change may need to be performed if driven 3000 miles within a month), etc. and create workflow for notifications and tasks.

Is this the best approach? or there are other solutions that are more solid.

Comment: Please tag your SharePoint version.

Answer (score 0):

From high level what you need is

1. List to store Vehicle Information
2. List to store rules (Oil change every 3000 miles, this way you are not hardcoding 3000 and in future if you want to change to 3500 you just need to update the list item
3. A Job - This job runs every night and do the calculation and updates list items accordingly. This job is also responsible for Notifications

I would prefer a Job over workflow in this scenario because its is easy to develop and maintain. On the other hand the workflow get complicated because of it need to run every day + other complexities related to calculations.